# Bad practice to use node_modules in src path?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, npm

I am trying to access a woff file from an installed npm package (extras) but it seems url prefixes the string with './'. And when removed url() and just try the string/parameter it does not work either.

Do I need to go through node_modules?

**file.css**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font';
  src: url('@extras/public/assets/icons/fonts/font.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Working below: but is it bad practice to reference node_modules?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font';
  src: url('/node_modules/@extras/public/assets/icons/fonts/font.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Comment: just `src: url("fonts/gts.woff") format("woff");`

Comment: Indeed using `node_modules` in the path is usually avoided, but it really depends on your path alias configuration. So without information about your project configuration, it is difficult to tell why your 1st attempt does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out url() prefixes the parameter with ./ if it starts with '@' or possibly any other string that is not a valid url.

The way that worked for me was to use an '@' alias in the url() is to prefix it with ~.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font';
  src: url('~@extras/public/assets/icons/fonts/font.woff') format('woff');
}
```